# AppDelegate.h errors - XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

This is really weird. When coming back from school today and firing up my Mac Mini, I open up Xcode and I am presented with two errors in my `AppDelegate.h` file. One of these errors says `Expected selector for Objective-C method` and the other one is `Expected method body`. I googled these two errors and found nothing that could solve my case. I have tried restarting Xcode and as well as my computer. I have also tried "Cleaning" the project and still my problem is not resolved. What could this error be? Is it on my end? Or is this an Xcode bug? Thanks:

Code: `AppDelegate.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window; 

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Your main.m File for any extra or invisible Code:

```
//
//  main.m
//  Demo
//
//  Created by Stackoverflow on 12/20/12.
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h" 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's in the corresponding .m file?

Are you @synthesizing accessors for your two properties? Failing to provide accessors (either synthesizing them or providing your own) seems like the most likely cause of the errors you've shown.

Have you implemented the usual app delegate methods? Off the top of my head, I'm not sure which if any app delegate methods are actually *required*, but your app isn't going to work very well and will produce some warnings if you don't have at least a `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:`.

Comment: Yes! all of my accessors are being synthesized in my corresponding AppDelegate.m! I also have the AppDelegate methods that were automatically implemented sigh Xcode in the file. Thanks!

Comment: I notice that you're also missing the braces `{...}` that are traditionally part of a class interface. I don't know if they're required, but I'd add them (right after your `@interface` line) even if they're empty.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have tried putting the curly braces where you instructed,  no new erros show but the other ones still persist. I want to say this is a bug with XCode, and maybe have to disable the option to where I cannot run my target if I have an error.

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode newer than 5.0, Anyone confronting this issue can from the top menu\Product\Build.
It should resume right in the spot.