# unexpected phonegap build error

Tags: ios, cordova

So everything was going nice, succesful build and testing on my device then phonegap gives me this error and my build fails. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling various versions, attempting to rebuild old projects building, updating and downgrading.. but nothing I've tried has worked. Any ideas?

Heres the error:

```
/Users/spencerpope/webslinger/platforms/ios/webslinger/Classes/AppDelegate.m:80:25: error: 
property 'useSplashScreen' not found on object of type
       'CDVViewController *'
        self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;
                    ^
1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
     CompileC build/webslinger.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/webslinger.build/Objects-        normal/i386/main.o webslinger/main.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC build/webslinger.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/webslinger.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o webslinger/Classes/AppDelegate.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
{ [Error: /Users/spencerpope/webslinger/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with           exit code 65] code: 65 }
   [error] /Users/spencerpope/webslinger/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with        exit code 65
```

Comment: ok I solved it, don't know how the problem arose, but I solved it.

Comment: Commented out `self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;` in AppDelegate.m then replace my main.m file with this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642216/appdelegate-h-errors-xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642216/appdelegate-h-errors-xcode)